# FontAwesome 5 mapping Error

Tags: pdftex, fontawesome, mapping, fontawesome5

**Problem**

I am using a custom document class from a book publishing company. When I include the `fontawesome5` in it, the compilation gives me a mapping error. If I do not use the custom document class then everything compiles fine. For this reason, it may not make much sense to provide a MWE since it is a custom document class. I have an older version of `fontawesome` installed and it works fine.

**Errors**

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-mapping.def:22: LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \faAdjust already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
...                                              
                                              
l.22 ...:nnnnn{\faAdjust}{adjust}{free0}{3}{"F042}
```

**Questions**

- I could not see it in the official documentation, but does `fontawesome5` support PDFLaTeX?
- I have managed to get `fontawesome5` to work with XeTeX and LuaTeX, but less successful with PDFLaTeX. How should I interpret the error message and is there a solution?
- I have also tried to install the `fontawesome.otf` font in my system (macOS Big Sur), but that did not seem to help. Is there something I could do to make latex recognize the font?

**Official documentation**

- FontAwesome 4: (works):
  https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf
- FontAwesome 5 (does not work):
  https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf

Comment: Yes, it does work with pdfLaTeX. Everything else is hard to say without seeing a MWE or at least the documentclass causing issues. But if I had to guess I would think that the class already loads he old `fontawesome` package. Loading both doesn't work since they define the same names.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger This was the problem, the document class loaded the old fontawesome package. Once I commented it out, everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `Control sequence \faAdjust already defined.` indicates that the command `\faAdjust` already existed before `fontawesome5` tried to define it. In most cases this indicates that the old `fontawesome` package (which defined the same icon name) has been loaded.

Since the `fontawesome` and `fontawesome5` packages share many command names, it is not possible to load both of them in the same document. So in order to use `fontawesome5`, `\usepackage{fontawesome}` has to be removed first.

After that you can use `fontawesome5` on all common engines (LuaLaTeX is recommended, but XeLaTeX, pdfLaTeX and classical (DVI based) LaTeX work too).